# Flex 4 - Add component to title bar of Spark Panel or Spark TitleWindow

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, components

I'm looking to add a couple of buttons to the title bar of a Spark Panel or Spark TitleWindow. Is this possible to do without making the panel from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this in the past by creating a custom Panel or TitleWindow skin that adds the additional buttons.  You would then extend the Panel/TitleWindow class and add your buttons as skin parts.  That way you can attach listeners, set icons, etc via your custom Panel/TitleWindow.

Here's a similar question/answer that adds an icon to a title bar: [Adding an image on the right side of the title bar of a panel in flex 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932926/adding-an-image-on-the-right-side-of-the-title-bar-of-a-panel-in-flex-4)

And an example that uses ActionScript rather than skins: [ActionScript example](http://dougr.net/?p=482)

Hope that helps.